# Debug Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jetty, maven

I am following below link to try to debug my maven project in Eclipse:
http://mahertb.blogspot.com/2006/08/debugging-maven-web-application-with.html

Somethings go fine until it throws an exception when I run it:
org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher class is not found.

But I've set D:\Installs\apache-maven-2.2.1\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar in user entries. (D:\Installs\apache-maven-2.2.1 is my M2_HOME).

Anyone has similar problem?

Or another aspect of same question: 
What is the trick of debugging Java application in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues before with using the Maven exec plugin to run things from within Eclipse. Instead, I use a class that I got from the Wicket quick start that runs Jetty from a public static void main.